# Why there is difference while reading the "O'max" string from csv file using golang?

Tags: angular, mongodb, go

I'm testing my code of importing a user record in the database. The code will running successfully and the user will import in the database but there is a problem while reading a string from the csv file. I'm using ubuntu making a csv file using software `LibreOffice Calc`. The files seems like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7mft.png). When I import this records then it will insert the record but I can't do any booking with this user because the software says the customer is not valid because of the "O'max". But when I give the manually entry to the software with same details then it will not create any error. Can anyone tell me what is the actual problem that there is problem while reading the name from csv file or any other issue?. The frontend is on the Angular.

FrontEnd :- Angular

BackEnd:- Golang

Database :- Mongodb

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code so that others can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GregoryHigley There is nothing special in code there is no validation in the code for this but in database it will do different entry for csv data it enters `O’max` and for manually entered data it will enter the string like `O'max`

Comment: @GregoryHigley Can you tell me why it make a difference of `'` `’`

Comment: Not without seeing the code and the input data. Computers are deterministic. So there _must_ be a difference of some kind between the two scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You may be unintentionally escaping the created SQL query unless I'm mistaken. Handle the character, or better yet rewrite your SQL query to be parameterized.

Without knowing what database you are trying to use it is hard to post material that may aid you in this situation.

Comment: see the eit I mention what database I'm using